# Get the index of the first or nth element of sparse bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, indexing

Is there a bash way to get the index of the nth element of a sparse bash array?

```
printf "%s\t" ${!zArray[@]} | cut -f$N
```

Using cut to index the indexes of an array seems excessive, especially in reference to the first or last.

Comment: What is a _sparse bash array_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If getting the index is only a step towards getting the entry then there is an easy solution: Convert the array into a dense (= non-sparse) array, then access those entries …

```
sparse=([1]=I [5]=V [10]=X [50]=L)
dense=("${sparse[@]}")
printf %s "${dense[2]}"
# prints X
```

Or as a function …

```
nthEntry() {
    shift "$1"
    shift
    printf %s "$1"
}
nthEntry 2 "${sparse[@]}"
# prints X
```

Assuming (just like you did) that the list of keys `"${!sparse[@]}"` expands in sorted order (I found neither guarantees nor warnings in [bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-arrays), therefore I opened another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54306133/6770384)) this approach can also be used to extract the nth *index* without external programs like `cut`.

```
indices=("${!sparse[@]}")
echo "${indices[2]}"
# prints 10 (the index of X)
```

```
nthEntry 2 "${!sparse[@]}"
# prints 10 (the index of X)
```

Comment: This is a great answer that also made it clear the difference between elements and indicies in a bash array.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you may use it like this using `read`:

```
# sparse array
declare -a arr=([10]="10" [15]="20" [21]="30" [34]="40" [47]="50")

# desired index
n=2

# read all indices into an array
read -ra iarr < <(printf "%s\t" ${!arr[@]})

# fine nth element
echo "${arr[${iarr[n]}]}"
```

```
30
```