# Getting first index of bash array

Tags: arrays, bash

Got a bash array where the indexes start at an arbitrary number and want to get the first index of the array.  Is such thing possible to do?

```
warg=([3]="-t" [4]="-s" [5]="-g")
```

I want to get the value `3`, the index of the first element of `warg`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the index of the first or nth element of sparse bash array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59395313/get-the-index-of-the-first-or-nth-element-of-sparse-bash-array); or maybe `awk '{print $1}' <<< "${!warg[@]}"` or `printf '%s\n' "${!warg[@]}" | head -1` ...

Comment: The way seems to involve storage to a non-sparse array.

Comment: have you tried that answer? did it not work for you? the non-sparse array is just a temporary construct to allow you to find the nth index

Comment: Yes, it is good.